# find_or_create_by causes SQLite3 PRIMARY KEY must be unique error

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sqlite

I'm using ActiveRecord with Ruby (no Rails) to interface with a SQLite3 database. I fetch some data from a web API and store it in the database using `find_or_create_by(some_hash)`. This works fine as long as the `some_hash` data is unique. If the `some_hash` already exists in the database, then the `find_or_create_by` method fails and gives the following sql error: SQLite3::ConstraintException: PRIMARY KEY must be unique.

I expected the `find_or_create` method first checks my database to see if the data already exists and if it does, then it will not create a duplicate entry. However if it doesn't find the data, then and only then it will create a new entry. So why do I get that error when `some_hash` already exists in the database like it was trying to save a duplicate entry?

How can I work around this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what worked:

```
A.create(some_hash) unless A.where("id" => some_hash["id"]).exists?
```

For some reason, querying the database with `some_hash` resulted in false positives and therefore I had to explicitly specify just the `id`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why its throwing that error at you, but if you want you can just break the method upinto its constituents:

```
A.create(some_hash) unless A.where(some_hash).present?
```

Hope that helps